# Past conditional -missed opportunities and past hypotheses

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If you **had told** me the truth, I would have believed you.
>
> If you **told** me the truth, I would have believed you.
>
> If he **had worked** harder, he'd have received a better grade.
>
> If he **worked** harder, he'd have received a better grade.

Which one is currect past perfect or simple past in if condition.

What is the meaning of above sentences ?

Comment: Check Swan's Practical English Usage sections 262.4 mixed tenses and 259.3 present use: situations that are no longer possible.

Comment: In the Disney American animated movie called Planes (2013), an airplane said to another:"If you **knew** the truth about my past, **would** you **'ve asked** me to train you?"

Answer (score 2):

*If you had told me the truth (in the past), I would have believed you (in the past)*.

The speaker is suggesting that on one or more occasions in the past 'you' did not tell the truth.

*If you told me the truth (generally), I would have believed you  (in the past)*.

The speaker is suggesting that not telling the truth is characteristic of 'you'